# Listing all collaborators of Github repository

Tags: python, github, github-api

I am trying to fetch all the users who have contributed to a given repository on github within a python script. I have made calls to the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) using urllib but it returns only a pre-defined list(and probably not a complete list) for each repository.

My calls look like

https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/contributors?page=2?access_token=fff

https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/contributors?page=1?access_token=fff

However, both of them point to the same json data.

So how should I list all contributors of the repo?

---

PS: I have input only in the form of `https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git`.

Comment: Note that `contributors` is not the same as `collaborators`. The later requires authentication to list.

Comment: Should rename this to "Listing all contributors of a Github repository". Collaborator is a different, higher rank/access level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the page number with an `?page=1` works for me. From the [Github Developer Guides](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/).

```
https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/contributors?page=2&access_token=fff
```

Comment: I made a pretty simple mistake! I didn't use `& ` in url, probably I am going to delete this question. I am sorry for the trouble

Comment: It isn't allowing it to delete, its going to be here anyway!